# Dump of some columns from certain tables at monthly interval

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

This is my first post and sorry for some clumsiness in formulating thoughts. I am managing quite large database for a digital library (140 tables, some of them with almost 3mln rows). I would like to collect monthly statistics for viewing objects in a postgresql database. The current numbers are in a table, call it "objects", with, among other, 'obj_id' and 'www_stats' columns for each object. This table has currently over 200 000 rows. What I want is to do some kind of monthly "dump" of 'obj_id' and 'www_stats' columns in such a manner that it will be accessible at any time (so ordinary dump to file is not good for this purpose). I searched for some solutions but didn't come across the one suitable for me. Can you suggest some reasonable solution for this?
Thanks in advance.

PS. I thought about making additional table obj_statistics with following columns: 'stats_id', 'obj_id', 'www_stats', 'timestamp', and copying relevant data to it, but such a table will have 2,5mln rows after a year and over 12mln after 5 years.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

It sounds like you want a monthly summary (rollup) of some of the data in your various tables. That requires 1) running some code each month, and 2) figuring out where to store the results.

There are many ways to run a regularly scheduled script, depending on your OS and deployment setting. For example, `cron`, or Postgres 13 and the `pg_cron` extension. Otherwise, you can do it with a script from whatever environment you are comfortable with.

For the results, they're now a new kind of information, and it makes good sense to store them in your database. For this you can use, at a minimum, a table or a "materialized view." Postgres supports piping query results into a table, see `SELECT INTO` and `INSERT INTO`. Alternatively, `CREATE` and `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW` can also absorb the output of a query.

Materialized views *seem* like an appealing option at first glance. however, no released version of Postgres has "incremental materialized views." Consequently, each time you want to add a month, you have to rebuild *all* of the months. The whole materialized view is rebuilt from scratch, not only with the new data.

Based on that last point, I'd suggest a table. That way, you can add just one month at a time to your summary results, without losing your old summary data along the way. This is particularly important in cases where you're discarding or archiving the original source data over time, but still want some rollup data to work with.

A couple of other points:

- It's always good to post what version of Postgres you're on, and how it's deployed. This helps people to provide answers that you can actually apply. (For example, PG 13 and `pg_cron` 1.3 are available, but not yet on all cloud providers, such as RDS.)
- Structure examples (code, not pictures) help to make your question more answerable.
- Your table and row counts aren't particularly big for Postgres. But getting good speeds out of databases requires understanding how to use indexes appropriately. And, in the case of Postgres, `CREATE STATISTICS` for various sorts of imperfect query plans.

I haven't included any syntax examples, but the Fine Documentation should have you covered there, or search the archives here, ask Mr. Google, etc.

Comment: Many thanks! Of course, I forgot to add version numbers. My postgresql is 11.9 and pg_cron (1.1.3-2) just installed. I think pg_cron and separate table is the solution I will work on. (I'm sorry I cannot give arrow up, my reputation is too low for now...)